# Exact sequences of projective modules

Tags: modules, exact-sequence, projective-module

Let 
$0{\rightarrow} K \stackrel{g}\rightarrow P\stackrel{f}\rightarrow Q \rightarrow 0$ 
and
$0\rightarrow K' \stackrel{g'}\rightarrow P'\stackrel{f'}\rightarrow Q \rightarrow 0$

be exact sequences of left $R$-modules. Assume that $P$ and $P'$ are projective.

How to prove that $P\oplus K'\cong P'\oplus K$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This result is known as [Schanuel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_lemma).

A quick proof is given by introducing the pullback of $f$ and $f'$. It is the submodule of $P\oplus P'$ given by 
$$X = \{(p,p')\in P\oplus P'\mid f(p) = f(p')\}.$$
Then, the following sequences are exact :
$$0 \longrightarrow \ker(f')\simeq K' \longrightarrow X \longrightarrow P \longrightarrow 0$$
and
$$0 \longrightarrow \ker(f)\simeq K \longrightarrow X \longrightarrow P' \longrightarrow 0,$$
where $X \longrightarrow P$ and $X \longrightarrow P'$ are the natural projections.
Since $P$ and $P'$ are projective, these sequences are split and one have :
$$K'\oplus P \simeq X \simeq K\oplus P'$$